plotly - how to plot multiple categories on by grouping on another criteria
I wish to plot the x-axis as years ['10 Years', '5 Years', '3 Years', 'TTM'] and group them for each stock. But the for loop is not working as expected.
mydict = {
  'Compounded Sales Growth' : ['10 Years', '5 Years', '3 Years', 'TTM', '10 Years', '5 Years', '3 Years', 'TTM'],
  'Stockname' : ['Stock-1','Stock-1','Stock-1','Stock-1','Stock-2','Stock-2','Stock-2','Stock-2'],
  'Compounded Sales Growth.1' : [1, 4, 12, 5, 7, 5, 24, 13]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(mydict)

fig = go.Figure()

# List of quarters
x = df['Compounded Sales Growth'].unique()

# Add traces for each metric
for result in df['Compounded Sales Growth'].unique():
    for stock in df['Stockname'].unique():
        fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
            x=x,
            y=df[ (df['Stockname'] == stock) & (df['Compounded Sales Growth'] == result) ].iloc[0,:],
            name=f'{stock}'
        ))

fig.update_layout()
fig.show()



If the x-axis is a category of time, then the loop process would just extract conditions by storage name. for stock in df['Stockname'].unique():     dff = df.query('Stockname==@stock')     fig.add_trace(go.Bar(         x=dff['Compounded Sales Growth'],         y=dff['Compounded Sales Growth.1'],         name=f'{stock}'         )) fig.show()

Its not a time dimension, we can say its the period though. In my example, it is fine to treat it as category. E.g. I want to compare sales growth of each stocks for 10, 5, 3 and trailing 12-months. so 4 categories on x-axis is fixed.

@r-beginners this works! Is there way to avoid df.query()?

Try this: import plotly.express as px;px.bar(df, x='Compounded Sales Growth', y='Compounded Sales Growth.1',color='Stockname', barmode='group')

thanks, please convert both of these to answer.

We have already received a similar response, so we will refrain from answering.
